# Selenium throws an error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with my autotests. It built on C# using Selenium.
On my VM everything works fine. I have dotnet version 6.0.300

But when I try to launch it on some other VM I ran in to a problem

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (chrome not reachable)
```

Before this exception, browser opens, but tab's title is "data:," same in address

Dotnet version is 6.0.407 on this VM, it is the only difference I found. Code is cloned from same repo and launched with same parameters. Could it be .NET SDKs difference? I don't think so, but I have no other ideas.

Here is chromedriver options, both VM on Windows. Also --incognito option is applied in code

```
"chrome": {
      "webDriverVersion": "Latest",
      "capabilities": {
        "enableVNC": true
      },
      "options": {
        "intl.accept_languages": "en",
        "safebrowsing.enabled": "true",
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": "0",
        "disable-popup-blocking": "true",
        "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
        "download.default_directory": "./downloads"
      },
      "startArguments": [
        "--start-maximized",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-popup-blocking",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
        "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors"
      ]
    },
```

I have no idea what caused an error. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Try starting chrome manually with `chrome_path`+`--start-maximized --no-sandbox --disable-popup-blocking --disable-gpu --disable-dev-shm-usage --remote-debugging-port=9222 --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ignore-certificate-errors` and include the error-message in your question

Comment: Just tried, and there's no error, browser opens fine with no data:, label

Comment: Mhh  and with "--incognito` additionally as well?

Comment: Yes, everything opens fine